# MySql - Find values that occur AT LEAST two times without using any aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

### Table:**City**

```
City_Name (PK)    State_Name (PK)    Population
--------------    ---------------    ----------
Austin            MA
Austin            TX
Burlington        VT
Fresno            CA
Houston           TX
Independence      KS
Independence      MO
Independence      PA 
Kansas            CA 
Kansas            MO
Paris             MO 
Paris             OR 
Paris             TX 
Paris             VA  
Paso              TX
```

The above table has a composite primary key (City_Name and State_Name). I want to **find the city which occur in at least two distinct States**. In this case, the result will be

```
City_Name
---------
Austin
Independence
Kansas
Paris
```

Other cities will not qualify as they don't occur in at-least two states.

This solution is required for practicing relational calculus problems and thus (unfortunately) aggregate function such as COUNT() cannot be used. I went through a database book where I saw a solution to similar problem which looks like this, but not working.

```
SELECT c1.State_Name FROM City AS c1
JOIN City AS c2 on c1.City_Name = c2.City_Name AND c1.State_Name = c2.State_Name
JOIN City AS c3 on c1.City_Name = c3.City_Name AND c1.State_Name = c3.State_Name
WHERE (c2.City_Name<>c3.City_Name) AND (c2.State_Name<>c3.State_Name);
```

Some help at this point will be highly welcoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't use any kind of aggregate functions, then the following would return the cities that appear at least twice

```
SELECT distinct c1.city_name 
  FROM `city` c1 
  JOIN city c2 
        ON c1.city_name=c2.city_name 
       AND c1.state_name!=c2.state_name
```

I assumed that not only COUNT but also any kind of aggegate was unavailable

Comment: It is too complicated for a task and may work slower than `group by ... having` approach. As for `count` and `group by` not available? This is ridiculous - all SQL engines have it

Comment: Joins are cheap, distincts might be harder but not in this case. As to why does the question specify that no aggregate function might be used... I don't know. It's not my place to judge. Proof of concept maybe?

Comment: Joins are never cheap. People go into great lengths to avoid them, for example even denormalize schema just to avoid joins (not that I suggest to do that, mind you)

Answer (score 6):

You can use COUNT(DISTINCT) and restrict your result with the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT City_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT State_Name)
FROM City
GROUP BY City_NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT State_Name) > 1
```

see documentation of [COUNT(DISTINCT)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr values.

I overlooked the restriction not be able to use COUNT(). That leads indeed to a self join:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT c1.City_Name
FROM
    City c1
INNER JOIN
    City c2
ON
    c1.City_Name = c2.City_Name
AND
    c1.State_Name <> c2.State_Name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/581ad/3) for both solutions.

Comment: Summing strings won't do much ;)  Try `count(distinct state_name) > 1`

Comment: DISTINCT State_Name - wrong condition, he need select duplicate City_Name

Comment: @VMai Thanks for the solution, unfortunately the solution has to be provided without using any aggregate function.

Comment: @Dmitry Bezik: If COUNT() was allowed, my solution would be right.

Comment: @rubiksKube: Overlooked that, so edited answer with a self join solution.

Comment: hey, I pointed that first. But I'm not a sore looser. Have an upvote anyway.

Comment: Hadn't read yours completely, I'm sorry. Upvoted you too, because it's the least I can do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT City_Name FROM City GROUP BY City_Name HAVING COUNT(City_Name) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `exists` subquery:

```
select  city_name 
from    city c1
where   exists 
        (
        select  *
        from    city c2
        where   c1.city_name = c2.city_name 
                and c1.state_name <> c2.state_name
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city FROM mytable
GROUP BY city
HAVING count(city) > 1
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05cc8/1)**